# Ajax Request on Safari not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have a HTML page with an ajax request that is working well on firefox, but safari doesn't do anything. when i am debugging, i see that readystate is undefined and status is "". Does anyone sees why it doesn't work on safari?

Javascript Code:

```
    <script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "pegSolitaireSettings.html", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function reloadGame() {
    location.reload();
}
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="demo">
  <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Settings</button>
  <div class="center-div">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is fixing your error for you while Safari is not.

You are attempting to request a relative URL: `"pegSolitaireSettings.html"`

Change that to: `"http://HOSTNAME/pegSolitaireSettings.html"` or `"//HOSTNAME/pegSolitaireSettings.html"` and it will work fine.

Where HOSTNAME is the domain name for the host.

Comment: thank you randy, but neither http://pegSolitaireSettings.html or //:pegSolitaireSettings.html are working

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer. You must use a fully qualified URL, I only put the file name with the host.

Comment: I tried with //MBP.local/Users/Study/Documents/RIA/PegSolitaire/pegSolitaireSettings.html where MBP.local is my host, but still nothing...

and it's still working in firefox

Comment: i also tried to add a vhost, i can access the file with the follwing url:
'http://www.pegsolitaire.com/pegSolitaireSettings.html'

But when doing it with xhttp.open("GET", "http://www.pegsolitaire.com/pegSolitaireSettings.html", true); nothing happens. It even don't work anymore in firefox like that. Please not that at the beginning i have http://

Answer (score 0):

This is what i actually have (simplified) and i can access `http://www.pegsolitaire.com/pegSolitaireSettings.html` in my browser, so the vhost should not be the problem

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css" type="text/css">
<script>
    function loadDoc() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
          this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "http://www.pegsolitaire.com/pegSolitaireSettings.html", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
 function reloadGame() {
  location.reload();
 }
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<div id="demo">
  <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Settings</button>
   <div id="gameInfo" align="center"> <br>
      <div class="values" id="totalTime"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```